# Function representing a Taylor Series

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

> Find a function represented by the Taylor series $\sum_{k=0}^{\inf}\left(-1\right)^{k}\left(\frac{3^{2k+1}}{\left(2k+1\right)!}\right)x^{2k}$.

After taking a bunch of derivatives, I figured out $f^n(x)=\frac{3^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$, which further simplified to $\frac{3(3x)^2k}{(2k+1)!}$. I'm stuck here, I think I have to use $\sin(x)$ somehow, but I can't figure out how. [Here's the graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/sioeyuwbdd). How should I continue?

Comment: I believe you mean $3^{2k+1}$ and not $3^{2k}+1$. Also, it is $$
f^{(2n)} (0) = ( - 1)^n \frac{{3^{2n + 1} }}{{2n + 1}}.
$$

Comment: Yes, sorry, I edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Taylor series for the Sine function as mentioned namely
$$\sin{(x)}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^kx^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$$
we have that your sum (provided at the link) is simply
$$\frac1{x}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k(3x)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}=\frac{\sin{(3x)}}{x}-3$$

Comment: Does your function pass "through" the origin when x approaches zero?

Comment: That's strange. I looked at the graph through the link the OP provided. It's a desmos graph that passes through the origin. The function I proposed in my comment matches the series perfectly,  again using the same desmos

Comment: @imranfat It seems that the OP wrote `$3^{2k}+1$` when they meant `$3^{2k+1}$`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Ah, that changes it a bit...

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question now, I got the answer, thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

The series for the sine is

$$\sin x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^kx^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}.$$

Now,

$$(3^{2k}+1)x^{2k}=\frac{(3x)^{2k+1}}{3x}+\frac{x^{2k+1}}x.$$
The function can be written as

$$\frac13\text{sinc}(3x)+\text{sinc}(x)$$ where $\text{sinc}$ is called the *cardinal sine*.